# First uncountable ordinal number

Tags: ordinals

Why is $\Omega$ the first uncountable ordinal number and not $\omega^\omega$? Isnt the latter a countably infinite product of countably infinite sets and hence uncountable?

Comment: and isn't a countable product of countable sets countable? ;)

Comment: I meant a countably inf product of countably inf sets. That is not countable, unlike the case of unions. For example, use some form of cantor diagonal argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **ordinal** exponentiation $\omega^\omega$ is a countable set. But is is not a countable product of countable sets. Instead it is the limit of $\omega^n$, all of which are countable.

As **cardinal** exponentiation $\omega^\omega=2^\omega$, and the question whether or not there is a smaller uncountable cardinal is known as the continuum hypothesis, and is unprovable from the usual axioms of set theory, that is from $\sf ZFC$.

---

**Related:**

1. [Cardinal Arithmetic versus Ordinal Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461430/cardinal-arithmetic-versus-ordinal-arithmetic/)
2. [Do $\omega^\omega=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154985/do-omega-omega-2-aleph-0-aleph-1/)