# Ordinal existence

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Is there any ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\omega ^ {\omega ^ \alpha} = \alpha$?

Could you please suggest me how to even try to solve this?

Comment: If $2^\alpha>\alpha$ (Cantor), then also $\omega^\alpha>\alpha$ and $\omega^{x}\geq x$ holds as well.

Comment: @Peter: That's true for cardinal arithmetic; not for ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I see; I don't understand it completely at this moment, so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: doesn't these identities hold for ordinal numbers? Can you have an $\alpha$ with $2^\alpha=\alpha$?

Comment: @Peter: In ordinal arithmetic $2^\omega=\omega$. This is not the same exponentiation as cardinal exponentiation. [See this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461430/cardinal-arithmetic-versus-ordinal-arithmetic/).

Comment: @AsafKaragila so the right answer is that it is the supremum of $\{\omega^{\ldots ^{\omega^\omega}}\}$?

Comment: @Peter: The right answer to which question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15403/discussion-between-peter-franek-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, I have a great dislike towards the chat system; and I have to leave my desk for a while now too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: no problem and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ordinals such that $\omega^{\alpha}=\alpha$ are called $\epsilon$-ordinals.
The first such, $\epsilon$ zero is a tower of exponents, 
$$\epsilon_0=\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\ddots}}}$$ 
(well I dont know how to make the diagonal dots go in the other direction)

It can be defined as follows
$$\epsilon_0=\sup \beta_n$$

where $\beta_n$ is defined as

$$\beta_0=\omega \qquad \beta_{n+1}=\omega^{\beta_n}.$$

The epsilon ordinals $\epsilon_{\nu}$ form a closed unbounded set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got the idea but I don't know how to prove that $sup \beta_n$ is an ordinal and that $\omega ^ \epsilon = \epsilon$

Comment: Well supremum of a set of ordinals is again an ordinal, this is a standard result. for the equality use the fact that $\omega^{\alpha}$ is continous.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** What happens if $\alpha=\omega^\alpha$? Can we even have that?